# Not all JDK sources found in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, java-7

I'm using Netbeans to develop a GUI program, and when I try to click the exception

```
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

instead of the source code I get the message :

```
Class "EventDispatchThread" not found in classpath
```

I get the same error when I try it with `javax.swing` classes. I have no problem seeing other classes like `System` for example. **Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong or what settings I'm missing?**

Below is a screenshot of my Netbeans Java Plattforms window.

[image: Netbeans Screenshot]

Details of my netbeans installation :

```
    Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.3.1 (Build 201306052037)
    Java: 1.7.0_40; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 24.0-b56
    Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_40-b43
```

Comment: Can you find the file when you unpack src.zip?

Comment: The error message is odd; why would it say "not found in **classpath**" this when looking for a Java source file?

Comment: Please post complete stack trace of the error please. The problem may be lying somewhere else.

Comment: @AaronDigulla yes, it's in the .zip

Comment: @gyan It's not so much about the exception per se, but about why netbeans can't find the source file.

Comment: @Aaron, it may be that the origin of the exception chain is missing some source code; which usually IDE debugger use to chain the lines and source code. the line number in stacktrace is not from source, rather it is taken from class itself. Also a simple reason that the source is not getting attached could be a reason.

Comment: @tmn29a: Do you see an error in the error log if netbeans?

Comment: @gyan I managed to get rid of the error, but am nonetheless puzzled as to why netbeans won't display those classes :$

Comment: @AaronDigulla Could you elaborate please ?

Comment: See http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqLogMessagesFile

Comment: @AaronDigulla I checked the log and there are only a few maven warnings.

Comment: Just curious, the "Default JavaFX Platform" in the screenshot is in red, was the JavaFX SDK installed and configured properly 0.0?

Comment: @高科技黑手 Yes, it was. But the error somehow 'resolved' itself. I'm not sure why or how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error somehow 'resolved' itself. I'm not sure why or how.